# What would happen if after using malloc it returned a NULL pointer and you went ahead and try to use that pointer?

Tags: c, malloc

I know that after using malloc, you have to make sure that the returned pointer is not NULL, but what if you didn't?

Comment: Dereferencing null is undefined behavior.

Comment: then ,I ask you a question, you create an array by this line: char str[3]="12"; then you read the value of str[5], what it should happen? you should never use  str[5] directly in this situation.

Comment: @peter__barnes accessing array outside its bounds is also undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding using a null pointer with the `*` operator, the 2011 C standard (committee draft N1570) says in clause 6.5.3.2, paragraph 4: “If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary ***** operator is undefined.” A footnote notes that a null pointer is an invalid value.

Many people will think of using a null pointer as trying to access memory with an invalid address, which causes an exception and terminates your program on common hardware and operating systems. However, modern compilers and their optimizers are very complicated and perform a variety of abstract mathematical transformations on your code. The result is that, if your code has undefined behavior, a variety of surprising things can happen.

Using a null pointer in other ways can also cause undefined behavior, including using it with the `->` operator, the subscript operator, the `+` and `-` binary operators, and the relational operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=`).

Comment: What if I clarified that I am in an intro to C class? An 'undefined behavior' is a bit ambiguous; I've read that in simpler programs you could expect a seg_fault when dereferencing a null pointer but it could vary in more advanced programs.

Comment: @DevAllanPer: Compilers do Very Complicated Things with code. When I was a kid, compilers were straightforward. They read your source and wrote assembly code a lot like a human writes. Today, though, they look at your program and try to solve the problem “How can I write a new short, fast program that does the same thing this big program does?” Then they write something completely new. The thing about that is, if some of what your program does is undefined, the compiler is allowed to change it to anything. So the result is just what falls out of anything else the compiler was doing.

Comment: @DevAllanPer: Undefined behavior is defined by the C standard as "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements". As far as the standard is concerned, that's *all* it means. The standard joke is that it can legally make demons fly out of your nose (of course it physically can't, but if it did it wouldn't violate the standard). In a sense, the worst consequence of undefined behavior is your program quietly behaving as you expected it to; it means it's going to be difficult to find the bug.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So could we say that the complexity of a compiler would affect its outcome? In other words, if I went to a really old machine and tried to dereference a null pointer it could lead to a different outcome compared to a newer machine?

Comment: @DevAllanPer: Yes.

Comment: Any chance we could reduce the vocabulary and verbosity if this answer for the OP? Quoting the C standard so extensively seems heavy-handed and doesn't specify what the OP can actually expect.

Comment: So I asked my professor this question once I got to class the next morning because this question seemed to cause a disagreement (a previous answer in which this disagreement occurred seems to have been removed). According to my professor, in our case (those just starting C or taking an intro to C class) you could expect a SEG FAULT when trying to use a NULL pointer produced by malloc. Just wanted to put this out there for the C newbies. :) Though, everything that previous users have said is true. So don't disregard that!

Comment: @DevAllanPer: “Expect” is vague. A segmentation fault is one result, and one that is frequent in simple situations. One can “expect” a segmentation fault in the sense it is likely to occur. One cannot “expect” a segmentation fault in the sense that it will necessarily occur.

Comment: @EricPostpischil an intro to C class is vague in general, it's just an answer to suffice those who are being introduced to the language (such as I am), though it is nice to know about the complexities of a seemingly simple question.